# Creating a multiplication table in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm having a little trouble figuring out why there's an extra "0" box on my multiplication table, and here's the code that I have so far:

```
$cols = 10;
$rows = 10;
$number = 0;
$number2 = 0;
echo "<table border=\"1\">";


for ($r = 0; $r < $rows; $r++){

echo('<tr>');
if ($r == 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
        echo('<td>' .$number2++.'</td>');
    }
}
for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++){
    if ($c == 0) {
        echo('<td>' .$number++.'</td>');
    } else if ($r != 0) {
        echo( '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td>');
    }
}
echo('</tr>');
}

echo("</table>");
```

So far it looks good, but that extra 0 on the first row is bothering me. Also I would like to keep the original format of the multiplication table if possible.

Comment: Because you echo it before incrementing it? `++number` might help but why not use `$i` and start from $i=1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is:

```
$cols = 10;
$rows = 10;
$number = 1;
$number2 = 0;
echo "<table border=\"1\">";


for ($r = 0; $r < $rows; $r++){

echo('<tr>');
if ($r == 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
        echo('<td>' .$number2++.'</td>');
    }
}

for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++){
    if ($c == 0 && $r != 0) {
        echo('<td>' .$number++.'</td>');
    } else if ($r != 0) {
        echo( '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td>');
    }
}
echo('</tr>');
}

echo("</table>");
```

You have a progression from 0 to 10. But, in the first td of the second for, you should not start from 0, you need to start from 1, or the 0 will be showed at the end of the first row. It's becase you already started the first row using the if, so the second one will repeat it.

You just need to check if the `$r` is 0 (to avoid repeat the first row) and start the `$number` from 1 (to follow the same logic, but starting from 1).

Comment: I would still like to keep the original format of the multiplication table, however I did try this code out, and there seems to be a "1" hanging on the end of the first row.

Comment: Yes! awesome, thank you for explaining what I did wrong there. I was trying to figure that out for almost 2 hours. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$cols = 10;
$rows = 10;
$number = 0;
$number2 = 0;

echo "<table border=\"1\">";

for ($r = 0; $r <= $rows; $r++){
    echo('<tr>');
    if ($r == 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
            echo('<th>' .$number2++.'</th>');
        }
    }
    for ($c = 0; $c <= $cols; $c++){
        if ($c == 0) {
            echo('<th>' .$number++.'</th>');
        } else if ($r != 0) {
            echo( '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td>');
        }
    }
    echo('</tr>');
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: That's almost good, but I would also like to keep the multiplication table up to 9 if possible, there was also a 0 still at the very end of the first row, that i'd still like to get rid of.

Comment: @TonyTaiNguyen Give me a moment. Will make it till 9 and remove the overlaps. `:)`